# SQL where join after/before condition

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

Are the requests something where I do JOIN first, and then add the conditions and where the first condition, and then JOIN.
Like this:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
form bla t1, blabla t2
where t1.id = t2.id
and t1.number = 3
```

OR

```
select t1.*, t2.*
form bla t1, blabla t2
where t1.number = 3
and t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: What do you observe when you run them?

Comment: It is not really clear what you  asking! Willl you ask if there is a difference between both Statements?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

The **best** and preferred solution would be to use **proper ANSI/ISO JOIN syntax** and avoid this question altogether:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, t2.*
FROM
    bla t1
INNER JOIN
    blabla t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE
    t1.number = 3
```